# Using different database values for BooleanField in Django

Tags: python, django, ms-access

I am converting an old MS Access database to a Django-based website. I've converted the data to a SQLite database, and automatically generated the models using `inspectdb` (which worked as well as could be expected).

It seems that MS Access stores boolean values as `-1` for `True` and `0` for `False`. Rather than modify the database (it is a *lot* of tables!) I'm trying to subclass `models.BooleanField`, as follows:

```
class MsAccessBooleanField(models.BooleanField):
    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        if value == -1:
            return True
        if value == 0:
            return False

    def to_python(self, value):
        if value == -1:
            return True
        if value == 0:
            return False

    def get_prep_value(self, value):

        if value == True:
            return -1
        if value == False:
            return 0
        return None

    def get_db_prep_value(self, value, connection, prepared=False):
        if value == True:
             return -1
        if value == False:
             return 0
        return None
```

When I view entries via the Admin interface, this seems to work (-1 values appear as Yes in the dropdown; 0 values as No).

However (this is the problem), when modifying the value and saving, I can only save as No or Unknown (selecting Yes produces a message that no value has been specified). Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: You seem to be overriding methods that should be used to cast the value.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain? Which method should I not be overriding?

Comment: What's _a lot_ of tables? I still think a migration would be your best bet.

Comment: 49... probably I should just do a migration anyway!

Comment: @user2672537 You'll need a string not integer.

Answer (score 2):

You'll only need to change the `BooleanField.to_python`

```
def to_python(self, value):
    if value in (True, False):
        return bool(value)
    if value in ('t', 'True', '1', '-1'):
        return True
    if value in ('f', 'False', '0'):
        return False
    raise exceptions.ValidationError(
        self.error_messages['invalid'],
        code='invalid',
        params={'value': value},
    )
```